# Information on Microsoft's Software Quality Metrics (.sqm) file format?

Tags: software-quality

i'm using Microsoft's `SqmApi.dll` library to add telemetry to an application. e.g.:

```
ISQM sqm = new Sqm("ContosoGrobber");

sqm.Increment(FileOpen, 1);
sqm.SetIfMax(QueryTime, stopWatch.Interval);
...

sqm.CloseSession(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath());
```

And now i have a `.sqm` file ready for me to `WebRequest` back to my web-server:

[image]

Now all i need is a way to crack open the guts inside the file:

> **`ContosoGrobber00.sqm`**:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> MSQMx       šwD                                      
> €Ÿ¨¡•æÌp¿Ÿ¤•æÌˆºX¦Ô|NÕï'CðÆÏ                                            
> g
> ```

Has anyone figured out the undocumented internal format used by every Microsoft product created in the last 8 years?

It's obviously not Base64 encoded, so presumably compressed.

### Bonus Reading

- [The Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program](https://www.verboon.info/2011/04/the-microsoft-customer-experience-improvement-programpart-2/)
- [Microsoft Open Specifications - Corporate Customer Experience Improvement Program Client-to-Server Protocol Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/main/ms-openspeclp/3589baea-5b22-48f2-9d43-f5bea4960ddb?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Channel 9 interview about Software Quality Metrics](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/jonudell/a-conversation-with-partha-sundaram-about-sqm-software-quality-metrics) (SQM) with Partha Sundaram

### Bonus Chatter

> [The Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program–Part 2](https://www.verboon.info/2011/04/the-microsoft-customer-experience-improvement-programpart-2/)
>
> ---
>
> for privacy reasons Microsoft doesn’t share any details in public about the SQM file format. The SQM file basically contains header data and Datapoints.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's some kind of MS standard serialization of the wire protocol?  The [MS-SQMCS client-server protocol doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh554823.aspx#Appendix_A_2) notes that the header begins with 0x4D51534D (hex for MSQM).